# Como alterar o valor de uma propriedade dado o seu nome

Tags: c#, .net, string, reflexão

No meu programa eu tenho algumas classes onde estão armazenados dados. Por exemplo

```
Class1.alfa.dado = 66;
Class1.beta.dado = 56;
Class1.gama.dado = 37;
```

O usuário vai selecionar em um ComboBox uma das opções que pretende alterar, nesse ComboBox estão as strings "alfa", "beta" e "gama".

Então eu preciso executar uma função que faça mais ou menos assim

```
void change (string alterar)
{
    Class1.(alterar).dado = 7;
}
```

Como usar essa string "alterar" para acessar a variável?

Uma solução seria utilizar o `switch`. Mas o problema é que as funções não são tão simples, são códigos grandes, e com o `switch` fica muito repetitivo e sempre que preciso alterar alguma coisa tenho que mexer em um monte de lugares. Gostaria de fazer isso de uma forma mais automática.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode utilizar uma combinação de:

- **`PropertyInfo`**: Permite a a observação e manipulação de características de tipos;
- **`Convert.ChangeType`**: Permite a mudança de tipos quem implementem `IConvertible` entre formatos durante tempo de execução.

Por exemplo, sua instância `Class1.alfa` poderia ter a propriedade `dado` alterada dinamicamente da seguinte maneira:

```
string propriedade = "dado";
string valor = "66";

PropertyInfo propertyInfo = Class1.alfa.GetType().GetProperty(propriedade);
propertyInfo.SetValue(Class1.alfa, Convert.ChangeType(valor, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é possivel executar diretamente nesse formato. O que daria certo é você verificar qual o valor da variavel alterar e utilizar um if, com as definições já que são poucas comparações, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
void change (string alterar)
{
    if ("gama".toString(alterar)){
        Class1.gama.dado = 7;
    }
    if ("beta".toString(alterar)){
        Class1.beta.dado = 7;
    }
    if ("alfa".toString(alterar)){
        Class1.alfa.dado = 66;
    }
}
```

Ao escrever a resposta, eu achei que estava em uma pergunta de JAVA, já que era uma tag que estava aberta no meu navegador... Não sei se em C# existe esse método.

Comment: O problema é que não são poucas comparações. Isso foi só um exemplo da funcionalidade que preciso para não ter que ficar colocando um código muito grande.

Comment: Então não sei ajudar :(

Comment: Se não me engano, em Java você também pode usar reflection para fazer a mesma coisa, utilizando a classe `Field`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html